# DataAccessException can not cast to SQLException to get error code and sql state

Tags: java, spring, sqlexception

The below snippet code is from Spring 5 Recipes book (page 386). I'm trying to run and test code but get `NullPointerException` for `sqle` variable and further seems there is no relation between `SQLException` and `DataAccessException` in Spring 5. Can someone tell me why and how?

```
package com.apress.springrecipes.vehicle;
...
import java.sql.SQLException;
import org.springframework.dao.DataAccessException;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ...
        VehicleDao vehicleDao = context.getBean(VehicleDao.class);
        Vehicle vehicle = new Vehicle("EX0001", "Green", 4, 4);
        try {
            vehicleDao.insert(vehicle);
        } catch (DataAccessException e) {
            SQLException sqle = (SQLException) e.getCause();
            System.out.println("Error code: " + sqle.getErrorCode());
            System.out.println("SQL state: " + sqle.getSQLState());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems e.getCause() is not of type SqlException. You colud print all stack trace before perform cast operation or use your IDE to debug it.

Comment: Is your `vehicleDao` `null`?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you never check if e.getCause() returns null or not.
If it returns null your code is vulnerable for NullPointerException

Second point is, why Spring change its way of handling database/jpa exceptions.
There are already some conversations about that. For example [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27869710/dataaccessexception-vs-sqlexception)

Or further you can check out book **"Spring in Action" by C. Walls** where in chapter about JDBC we can read.

(10.1.1 Getting to know Spring’s data-access exception hierarchy)

> On one hand, JDBC’s exception hierarchy is too generic—it’s not much
>   of a hierarchy at all. On the other hand, Hibernate’s exception
>   hierarchy is proprietary to Hibernate. What we need is a hierarchy of
>   data-access exceptions that are descriptive but not directly
>   associated with a specific persistence framework.

I highly recommend whole subchapter to understand this topic.

Comment: No problem. If you think that my answer was helpful please make sure to upvote IT and Mark as a answer